# Ruby on Rails Loop Has-Many relationships Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am trying to loop through and add 1 to the correct when the result.correct_node attribute is equal to the dashboard.questions.answer.text attribute but for some reason this loop doesn't work.

My logic was:
1. Loop through each question, loop through all of the results checking if their assigned questionid is equal to the question's id, if so, check if the text and correct_node is the same, and add 1 to the correct variable. Then do this for each question.

From what I can tell when I debug the loop the if statement isn't working correctly, and there are general problems with how I am doing this.

The relationships for the object are as such.

Dashboard has-many questions. Questions has many answers. Results has attributes questionid and correct_node.

```
@correct = 0
@wrong = 0
@dashboard.questions.map do |question|
        @results.each do |result|

            if question.id == result.questionid

                question.answers.map do |answer|
                    if answer.text == result.correct_node
                        @correct = @correct + 1
                    else
                        @wrong = @wrong + 1
                    end
                end
            end
        end
end
```

If someone could let me know how I might go about fixing this or what is wrong it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]".

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. If there is a problem with the details I've provided, please let me know what is needed and I'd be more than happy to provide it.

Comment: Does your question match what the help document says you need? If not then add the missing info. Start at that point and then we can ask if we need something. Your code isn't testable, we have to guess what your variables contain, whether the rows in your DB contain what we think they do, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the loop works, the error was as a result of messing with the values of the variables. Thanks.